# PHP curl for data from website returning empty arrays

Tags: php, curl, domdocument, simple-html-dom

I am trying to write a Php Script to pull snow and other data from www.snowbird.com/mountain-report/ to display via an led array. I am having troubles with getting the data I need. I can't seem to be able to find a way to make it work. Would I be able to make this work, or would I have to go about and use a different language?

The following code only return empty. Following the code I will post what is returned.

```
<?php
require('simple_html_dom.php');

$ch = curl_init("http://www.snowbird.com/mountain-report/");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);
$content = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$html = new simple_html_dom(); 
$html->load($content);

$ret1 = $html->find('.snowfall-total');
print_r ($ret1);
$ret2 = $html->find('#twenty-four-hour');
print_r ($ret2);
$ret3 = $html->find('#forty-eight-hour');
print_r ($ret3);
$ret4 = $html->find('#current-depth');
print_r ($ret4);
$ret5 = $html->find('#year-to-date');
print_r ($ret5);
?>
```

Here is the output

```
pi@KPi /var/www $php test4.php

Array
(
)
Array
(
)
Array
(
)
Array
(
)
Array
(
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The website you are trying to request from throws an error when using cURL because the google tools they have implemented in their python code crash when there is no user agent set.

Try adding this line to your code before `curl_exec($ch)`

`curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13');`

And as @jeroen said, using `json_decode($content, true)` is not neccesary as the returned data will be HTML code not a json string. Remove that line as well and you should be good to go.

Comment: After adding this It seems to have changed, I will let you know when I am successful in finding the data I want. So far so good. Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

The url you are loading is returning a web-page: html.

So when you treat it as a json string in:

```
$content = json_decode($content, true);
```

You will set your `$content` to null as that is what is returned when `json_decode()` cannot decode the string / the input is not valid json.

If they have an api that returns json, you could use that, otherwise you can leave out the `json_decode` line and take it from there.

Comment: Thank you very much, I took that out of my code as well as in my question.

Answer (score 1):

If you tried outputting the `$content` variable right after doing the cURL, you would notice that the website throws a humongous error message.

The error is basically some user-agent check that the website expects which you do not provide.

If you insert this before you do your `curl_exec()`, you will get the content correctly:

```
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13');
```

With that said, you will still get nothing because you're trying to decode JSON while the website does not return you a JSON string. This needs to be removed:

```
$content = json_decode($content, true);
```

Now everything should work as you want it to.

Comment: Thank you very much for summing it all together! It seems to be working better now. I will let you know once I get it to do everything I want it to!